# SharePoint 2013 - restore a single site from site collection backup

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, restore

I want to restore a single sharePoint site from a site collection backup. 
My question is, is this possible. And how is this possible.

Are there any useful commands?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can't restore a site from site collection backup. Couple of things you can do.

So big thing, if you have access to Production farm.

1. You can export the Site from production and restore it. Use [export-spweb](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607895.aspx) & [import-spweb](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607613.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
2. You can use the Central admin and export the site.
3. If you have the Content Database Backup then you can export the web using the [Unattached Content Database method](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh269602.aspx). Then import it.
4. If you have site collection backup then restore the site collection in different farm then export and import the site.

Answer (score 1):

A Site Collection backup contains all Webs within the Site Collection. It is not possible to extract any one particular Web from the Site Collection for restore.

Comment: How can I restore a single site in a different way?

Comment: Using an unattached Content Database backup will allow you to restore down to the List level, if you want. That is the route I'd take barring 3rd party migration tools.

Comment: Can you please explain how this works?

Comment: @TrevorSeward is this possible to share your experience with 3rd party tools and name of them and demonstrate benchmark  or give us links

Answer (score 0):

at first run SharePoint Management Shell
then past the below code..

```
Restore-SPSite http://sptest/sites/testbackup -Path C:\backupfile.bak -force
```

here:

`http://sptest/sites/testbackup  --->` is the site collection name.

`C:\backupfile.bak   --->` is the file path.

Comment: This answer won't work for the OP, since this will overwrite the entire site collection with the backed up data.  He wants to restore a single site within a site collection using a site collection backup.